# Email personalize with %%Firstname%%

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

We have an issue: We have email templates with personalization %%first name%% however when we preview the email with the DE which doesn't have any column like First name it's an throwing error. Can anyone help me to avoid this error. It would be great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, you are using a space within the personalization string ie. `%%first name %%`. Try changing it to `%%firstname%%` (AmpScript is case insensitive so case shouldn't matter)

**UPDATE**

From your comments, I see the issue around using a DE that does not contain the "First Name" Column it in. The above will still work assuming the firstname is a profile attribute.

If you wish you use DE column values, you should use the [LookUp function](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookup/#Lookup) and call it with the [v](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/v/#v)

Reference:

- [Personalization Strings](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/)